# How to Fetch 16 Bytes from Global Memory or Texture memory

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia

I have not tried this yet, because I'm not sure how to implement this and would like to have an idea if this is even possible.

I read about the int4 type, and I was wondering, since each of my thread need to operate on 1byte of memory at tId (of an array) and then work on the next 15 bytes, would it be possible for me to send an array of int or int4 to global or texture memory, such as this one

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ...
```

where Thread0 would then fetch byte0 to 15, Thread1 fetch byte1 to byte 16 and so one, to reduce the number of global memory access i'm doing, because at the moment, I make at maximum 16 readings per threads to global memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch 16 bytes in a single transaction, the data must be a proper vector type (e.g. `int4`, `float4`, etc.) and it must be *naturally aligned*. That means, the start of the vector type region for a 16-byte vector type must begin on a 16-byte boundary. If your first thread retrieved bytes 0-15 correctly, the second thread could not retrieve bytes 1-16 correctly (in a single transaction), because that would not be naturally aligned. The next naturally aligned 16-byte slot would be bytes 16-31. `int` also has to be aligned, so you could not start an `int` at byte 1, but at bytes 0, 4, 8, etc.

[This section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) of the programming guide, in particular "Size and Alignment Requirement" will explain it also.